# php editable grid - different combo box cells

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I am using a [php editable grid](http://www.editablegrid.net/) in order to update some data. Is it possible for the cells that are comboboxes, to have different values per row?

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: suggest using a grid with better documentation and API like datatables.js. It has demos for integrating jEditable plugin and full details for cell rendering functions. Also is heavily used with good support

Comment: Please provide a link and write it as an answer, in order to mark it as answered. Thanks